# Alternativas a passar dados por campos hidden

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Estou criando um sistema, onde sempre preciso do id do meu objeto no BD, e na maior parte do sistema envio esse id da VIEW pro controller usando os campos hidden com um POST.

Se falando de segurança qual o melhor jeito de se fazer isso?

Acho meio inseguro utilizar esse método. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Na documentação do Laravel tem explicando sobre Session http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só vai ser inseguro, se seu sistema tiver brechas de segurança, caso contrário o usuário não poderá fazer nada com um ID. Mas se tiver utilizando algum certificado ssl por exemplo, poderá criar um cookie ou até uma session para registrar o ID na hora que acessar a view. Não mascara 100%, mas impede de ser editado.

Comment: Eu estou tratando qualquer tentativa de alteração no controller, mas pensei que existisse um metodo mais recomendado para isso.

Comment: Isso não é um problema tão grande assim, como o ID geralmente é formado por números, fica fácil tratar contra códigos maliciosos. Como citei, o cookie seguro pode ser uma boa pra vc, pois ele não pode ser editado. Mas se for de suma importância que o usuário nem visualize o id, me fale que tenho uma alternativa.

Comment: O que você acha de sessions? Seria de mesma segurança do cookie?

Comment: Você pode utilizar sessions sem problemas, na verdade vai ser até melhor. Lembrei que a session não pode ser visualizada pelo usuário, pois é armazenada no servidor e não no navegador. Cada session gera um id que é armazenado no navegador, mas o conteúdo dela fica apenas no servidor.

Comment: Desculpe por outra pergunta leiga, esse caso da sessions ser armazenadas o conteúdo apenas no servidor, é uma funcionalidade do laravel? ou são características dela mesmo?

Comment: Característica dela mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a melhor alternativa é utilizar o próprio recurso do framework, no que diz respeito a esse `id` que você quer passar.

## parametros pela URL e findOrFail

Controller:

```
public function anyEdit($id)
{
    $usuario = Usuario::findOrFail($id);

   return View::make('...', ['usuario' => $usuario]);
}
```

View:

```
{{ Form::model($usuario); }}
```

No caso do Controller exemplificado, o método `findOrFail` garante que o usuário deve existir no banco na hora de editá-lo.

Passando no input hidden, corre o risco de alguém editar os dados (com a ferramento do desenvolvedor por exemplo) e causar problemas para sua programação.

No caso do `findOrFail` pegando o `id` pela url `usuario/edit/1`, se ele colocar um id não existente, o `Laravel` irá retornar uma exceção.

Já no caso do `Form::model()`, passamos o usuário, para poder preecher automaticamente os campos com o valor desejado.

## Segurança com o Input Hidden

Dá para aplicar uma segurança extra na hora de passar os dados pelo input hidden.

Suponhamos que você quer validar que aquele campo do `input hidden` e garantir que o ID exista no banco. Você pode usar a validação `exists` para isso:

```
$rules = [
     'hidden_id' => 'required|exists:tabela,id_dessa_tabela'
];

Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

## Controle de Níveis

E em um terceiro caso vamos imaginar que você tenha o model `Produto`. E você tem dois tipos de usuário no sistema (administrador e comum).

O comum não poderá editar o campo `usuario_id` de `Produto`; O administrador poderá.

Você pode usar o método `reguard` para proteger os dados do model. E `unguard` para desfazer a proteção.

Você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
class BaseController extends Controller

{
   public function __construct()
   {
      if (Auth::user()->nivel !== 'administrador') {
         Produto::reguard();
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: tenho que melhorar, mas faço isso depois. O teclado do meu cunhado é diferente do que estou acostumado a usar :)